# Issue with pcr in qualityTools

Tags: r, plot

I've encountered an issue when using the pcr function in qualityTools to plot the process capabilities

```
install.packages("qualityTools")
library(qualityTools)
x = rweibull(1000, 2, 8) + 1000
pcr(x, "weibull", lsl = 100, usl = 117)
```

The histogram background is covered with numbers!  Not sure what went wrong.  Can somebody please take a look?

Thanks!

[image: The histogram background is covered with numbers!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by calling `pcr` with the argument `xlab = ""`, i.e.

```
pcr(x, "weibull", lsl = 100, usl = 117, xlab = "")
```

---

*Explanation.*  An inspection of `pcr` shows that it is calling `hist` using `do.call` in the following way:

```
do.call(hist, c(list(x[, 1], freq = FALSE, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, main = ""), parList))
```

This construct creates a name for the input that concatenates all the values of the vector.  This name is then displayed as the x-axis label.  You can replicate this behavior by calling, e.g.

```
do.call(hist, c(list(rnorm(3), main = "")))
```

The solution is to set `xlab = ""`.

Comment: Thanks very much! It's awesome!